# React Native - How to memoize a component correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

This is my parent component:

```
const A = () => {
   const [data, setData] = useState([]);
   const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

   const isFetching = useRef(false);
  
   ...

   const fetchMoreData = async () => {
      if(isFetching.current) return;

      isFetching.current = true;

      setIsLoading(true);
      
      try {
        const newData = await ... 

        setData([...data, ...newData]);
      } 
      catch(err) {
         ...
      }

      setIsLoading(false);

      isFetching.current = false;
   }

   ...

   return <B data={data} isLoading={isLoading} onEndReached={fetchMoreData} />
}
```

And I am trying to memoize my child component B, to avoid unnecessary re-renders. Currently, I am doing the following:

```
const B = memo(({ data, isLoading, onEndReached }) => {
   ...

   return (
     <FlatList 
        data={data}
        isLoading={isLoading}
        onEndReached={onEndReached} 
     />
   );
}, 
(prevProps, nextProps) => {
    return JSON.stringify(prevProps.data) === JSON.stringify(nextProps.data) &&
       prevProps.isLoading === nextProps.isLoading;
});
```

But, I think, that my memoization can cause problems... as I am not adding `prevProps.onEndReached === nextProps.onEndReached`

But... all works fine :/ Btw I suppose that there can be a little chance to see unexpected things happening because of not adding it. What do you think? Is it necessary to add methods in the `areEqual` method?

Comment: Why not `const MemoizedB = memo(B)` and then `return <MemoizedB ..` in your `<A />` component?

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov why memo without areEqual method?

Comment: I think  not including `onEndReached` might be a problem if you're updating a state inside it which `onEndReached` closes over. So suppose `onEndReached` which closes over a state value gets passed to `B` and `B` doesn't render because `data` and `isLoading` don't change for 4-5 renders. Now you call `onEndReached` and it updates the state in `A` incorrectly. If it has nothing to with state or can update state purely based on previous state (like `setState(state=>state+1)`), not passing it to areEqual would be fine I think.

Comment: @LakshyaThakur In my example, do you think it is necessary? I think that yes because of doing setData([...data, ...newData]) instead of setData((prevData) => [...prevData, ...newData]);   Also, what about the ref? If the method is not re-defined (as it is not included in the memo's areEquals) will it be able to access the most up-to-date value of the ref? I think that yeah right? Maybe I am wrong

Comment: Since `ref` is independent of renders, it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thx man. Love u.